# Sails.js default app fails to start with MongoDb

Tags: sails.js, sails-mongo

I created a WebApp with `sails new my-app` and am trying to use mongodb as its database. I am running mongodb in docker and am able to connect to the database using GUI tools like MongoDB Compass. Using that tool I created `todo_list` database in mongo.

In the app, I changed default datastore in datastores.js to:

```
default: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    url: 'mongodb://root:rootpassword@localhost:27017/todo_list'
}
```

This connection string is correct as verified by using it to connect via MongoBD Compass.

When I run `sails lift` I get:

```
error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
error: Could not tear down the ORM hook.  Error details: Error: Consistency violation: Attempting to tear down a datastore (`default`) which is not currently registered with this adapter.  This is usually due to a race condition in userland code (e.g. attempting to tear down the same ORM instance more than once), or it could be due to a bug in this adapter.  (If you get stumped, reach out at http://sailsjs.com/support.)
```

I saw this error raised in a few github issues, bu tteh answers were irrelevant to my situation. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you start the app with `migrate` set to the value "drop"?